# How can sizeof childclass be used in a parent template class with the child class as a template argument?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm reverse engineering and recreating a program which implements global static singletons. "A" would be a class that is stored in the singleton, and "B" is the singleton itself. Is there any way to make the following code work?

```
template <class TClass>
class B
{
    static char cBuffer[sizeof(TClass)];
};

class A : public B<A> {
  int a;
  int b;
};
```

This code snippet generates the following error:

```
<source>:4:22: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'A'
        static char cBuffer[sizeof(TClass)];
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:7:18: note: in instantiation of template class 'B<A>' requested here
class A : public B<A> {
                 ^
<source>:7:7: note: definition of 'A' is not complete until the closing '}'
class A : public B<A> {
      ^
```

Comment: Why do you need to do something like this? What is the underlying problem you want to solve? If it's just plain curiosity then that's okay, but please state so in the question. Otherwise please ask about the actual underlying problem instead, or this question is just an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm reverse engineering a program which implements global static singletons. "A" would be a class that is stored in the singleton, and "B" is the singleton itself.

Comment: Note that the preferred way to create a templated singleton in C++ would be `template<typename T> T& getInstance(){ static T theInstance; return theInstance; }`

Comment: Are you reverse-engineering somebody else's working code or are you trying to get your own non-functional code running? I'm a bit confused

Comment: I'm reverse engineering a binary and trying to reimplement it pretty much exactly the same.

Comment: @Magusviper the C++ compilation process is extremely complex and the resulting compiled binary may have extremely little in common with the C++ source code. Why use templates at all, since they certainly don't appear in the binary?

Comment: I do have the symbols for the program, so I know that the templates are being used. This is all purely for educational purposes, I'm not trying to implement this in any real world application. Btw, the preferred way to create a templated singleton wouldn't work here, since the original code uses lazy initialization, and "static T theInstance;" immediately calls the constructor.

Comment: @Magusviper nope, my example code uses lazy initialization because it's a function-local static variable. Look up the Meyer's Singleton.

Comment: I'm assuming you are planning to placement-`new` construct `A` in `cBuffer`? If so you need to think about the alignment with `alignas`, otherwise you will be causing undefined behavior due to unaligned access. This does not seem like a wise approach, even if this is intended to be modeling some reverse-engineered process.

Comment: Within CRTP, `T` is incomplete type. Do you really need CRTP, Isn't `struct A_impl{int a; int b;}; template <typename T> class B {/*as-is*/}; using A = B<A_impl>;` sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this but it's less than ideal:

```
template <class TClass>
class B
{
    static char cBuffer[];
};

class A : public B<A> {
  int a;
  int b;
};

template <>
char B<A>::cBuffer[sizeof(A)];
```